# SSL issue and redirects from https to http

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https

I have a site www.example.com for which i purchased SSL cert and installed.

And it was working fine, I also have a subdomain with app.example.com which was not on SSL.

Both www.example.com and app.example.com are on same IP address.

At later we decided to put SSL only on app.frostbox.com and then i configured SSL with app.frostbox.com and it worked fine,

Now the issue is that Google is indexing my site as https://www.example.com/ and when users hits the web , Invalid security warning is issued and when user allow security issue they are shown my app.example.com contents.

Note: I have my SSL configuration files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

The contents of the ssl.conf are below.

http://pastebin.com/GCWhpQJq

NOTE: I tried solutions in .httaccess but none of those worked. Like redirecting 301 redirects etc

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: In your case, you can use WildCard SSL Certificate too, which cost you bit lower than SAN Multi Domain SSL.

Comment: @JonLin : Google indexing site as https and https shows security warning so i want to redirect to non https.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a SAN-multi domain certificate.  Issue the certificate to www.abc.com and add the additional SAN www.app.abc.com in and it will work.

Hopefully you are within the 30 day cancellation policy.

Comment: issue is that my management do not want to purchase wildcard certificate. :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit your httpd.conf file or the file where your virtual host is specified and add these lines to redirect http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Hi, I dont want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. its https->http

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} - Use this edited code in your .htaccess file. It reverse redirection code.

Comment: Redirections from HTTPS to HTTP happen too late, the certificate will have already been presented to the client by then.